# Bot enemies as an use case actor

Tags: system, actor, use-case

This is so confusing.
I know the actor is an external agent interact with the system.
Bot as we all know is part of a system. On the other hand, they can act as player does.

So can I make a bot as an actor in use case? just like player?
But if so, it contradicts the concept of actor itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a system can be an actor to another system and a bot could be considered a system that operates with a higher degree of autonomy.

For example a web bot (or web crawler) is a semi-autonomous system that makes HTTP requests to another system (e.g. a web server) to fetch HTML pages. In this example a web bot is both an actor and a system in it's own right.

"An actor in the Unified Modeling Language (UML) specifies a role played by a user or any other system that interacts with the subject.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_%28UML%29